# Webscrape Beautifulsoup on website (get multiple hrefs)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape this webpage (carbuzz.com). I want to get the links (href) of all the car brands from "Acura" to "Volvo" ([link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpKmw.png)).

Currently, I only get the first entry (Acura). How do I get the remaining ones? As I just started scraping and coding would highly appreciate your input!

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

#Inputs/URLs to scrape:
URL2 = ('https://carbuzz.com/cars')
(response := requests.get(URL2)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

car_brand = overview.find(class_='bg-make-preview')['href']
car_brand_url ='https://carbuzz.com'+car_brand

print(car_brand_url)
```

Output:

```
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_all` to get the tag with class name `bg-make-preview`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for elem in soup.find_all(class_='bg-make-preview'):
    car_brand_url ='https://carbuzz.com' + elem['href']
    print(car_brand_url)
```

This gives us the expected output

```
https://carbuzz.com/cars/acura
https://carbuzz.com/cars/alfa-romeo
https://carbuzz.com/cars/aston-martin
https://carbuzz.com/cars/audi
https://carbuzz.com/cars/bentley
https://carbuzz.com/cars/bmw
https://carbuzz.com/cars/bollinger
https://carbuzz.com/cars/bugatti
https://carbuzz.com/cars/buick
https://carbuzz.com/cars/cadillac
https://carbuzz.com/cars/caterham
https://carbuzz.com/cars/chevrolet
https://carbuzz.com/cars/chrysler
https://carbuzz.com/cars/dodge
https://carbuzz.com/cars/ferrari
https://carbuzz.com/cars/fiat
https://carbuzz.com/cars/fisker
https://carbuzz.com/cars/ford
https://carbuzz.com/cars/genesis
https://carbuzz.com/cars/gmc
https://carbuzz.com/cars/hennessey
https://carbuzz.com/cars/honda
https://carbuzz.com/cars/hyundai
https://carbuzz.com/cars/infiniti
https://carbuzz.com/cars/jaguar
https://carbuzz.com/cars/jeep
https://carbuzz.com/cars/karma
https://carbuzz.com/cars/kia
https://carbuzz.com/cars/koenigsegg
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lamborghini
https://carbuzz.com/cars/land-rover
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lexus
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lincoln
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lordstown
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lotus
https://carbuzz.com/cars/lucid
https://carbuzz.com/cars/maserati
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mazda
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mclaren
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mercedes-benz
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mini
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mitsubishi
https://carbuzz.com/cars/nissan
https://carbuzz.com/cars/pagani
https://carbuzz.com/cars/polestar
https://carbuzz.com/cars/porsche
https://carbuzz.com/cars/ram
https://carbuzz.com/cars/rimac
https://carbuzz.com/cars/rivian
https://carbuzz.com/cars/rolls-royce
https://carbuzz.com/cars/spyker
https://carbuzz.com/cars/subaru
https://carbuzz.com/cars/tesla
https://carbuzz.com/cars/toyota
https://carbuzz.com/cars/volkswagen
https://carbuzz.com/cars/volvo
https://carbuzz.com/cars/hummer
https://carbuzz.com/cars/maybach
https://carbuzz.com/cars/mercury
https://carbuzz.com/cars/pontiac
https://carbuzz.com/cars/saab
https://carbuzz.com/cars/saturn
https://carbuzz.com/cars/scion
https://carbuzz.com/cars/smart
https://carbuzz.com/cars/suzuki
```